# convergence and divergence of alternate series with higher power in denominator

Tags: calculus

How can i find whether the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^8}$$ is convergentvor divergent.

What i try

I am trying to solve it using alternate series test

Let $\displaystyle a_{n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ . Then $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^8}.$

Here $$|a_{n}|>|a_{n+1}|$$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^8}\rightarrow 0$

So we can say that series is converge.

Can anyone tell me is my way is right. If not then please tell me how i solve it. Thanks

Comment: Do you know the alternating series test? If yes, what happens when you apply it?

Comment: This series converges absolutely, by comparison with the integral.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin . Its nth terms goes to 0.

Comment: @Lulu how can i campare with integral like $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x^8}dx$

Comment: The absolute series, minus $1$,  is less than $\int_0^{\infty} \frac {dx}{x^8}$. (consider the Riemann Sum with rectangles of width $1$ and heights at $\frac 1{2^8}, \frac 1{3^8}, \cdots$). Note:  absolute convergence is stronger than conditional convergence, so this is a stronger result than  the one obtained via the alternating series test.

Comment: @jacky The alternating series test states that if a function changes signs every term and if the limit of the nth term while n approaches infinity goes to 0, the series converges.

Comment: @JadenLee  It is important to note that the alternating series test requires that the terms  be $\textit {decreasing}$ to $0$ (in absolute value), not just that they approach $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^8}$ converges (for example, by comparison to the convergent series $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n (n + 1)}$,  whose terms you can express as $\frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n}$, and so they telescope), and since it converges your alternating series is absolutely convergent.